# Does sputtering Au on top of PEDOT:PSS thin film alter its properties?

Tags: electrical-resistance, capacitance, material-science, polymers

I have grown thin films (~100-500 nm) of PEDOT:PSS by electrodeposition on top of thin films of Au (~1 nm) and now I want to measure the impedance of the PEDOT:PSS thin film.
To accomplish this I am thinking of depositing another layer of Au (or another conducting metal) on top of the PEDOT:PSS for it to act as a capacitor and use 4 probe method to measure its impedance.

However I am apprehensive that by using a magnetron sputtering technique to deposit Au on top of the PEDOT:PSS thin film will alter its properties, rendering the impedance measurements unviable.
I can also do IBD deposition of Au, but I think this will be worse. I could also electrodeposit Au, however in doing that I needed to apply a negative potential which would reduce the deposited PEDOT:PSS rendering it non-conductive.

Opinions on how to deposit a conducting (can be very thin) layer on top of PEDOT:PSS without interfering with it ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about electroplating?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. However as I said electroplating (or electrodeposition) of Au requires negative potential which would reduce the already deposited PEDOT:PSS into its non-conducting state.